# Url rewriting in folder project

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use subdomains a lot for webs and everytime i use url rewriting like this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1
```

so if i use **sudomain.domain.com/something** its ok and it shows me index.

But now i try to use it on website which i have only in folder so adress is like.

```
domain.com/newwebsite/
```

i need same system here, so if i put **domain.com/newwebsite/somepage** it will be ok and it shows me index page like example before.

Comment: is there a `index.php` inside the newwebsite folder?

Comment: yeah, here is website content, so index.php too

Comment: it won't work. domain.com/newwebsite/about for.e. i will get Not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in `/newwebsite/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newwebsite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```